# Accessing column's value in datagridview

Tags: c#

I have a datagrid getting its data from the database. This datagrid has a column named "Room number".

I want to add content double click event so that when the user clicks on a specific room number database should be accessed and get the data related to that room number from database and display it on a separate form.

How to access this column by name that is "Room Number"?

```
private void dgMaster_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: if Solution is good than why not accept it.......?

Comment: i tried to accpet it it said wait for 5 minutes and then i got busy with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of room number by this... i assume here that your `room number` column is of type `int`.

```
private void dgMaster_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   int roomNumber = Convert.ToInt32(dgMaster.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Room number"].value);
}
```

You can also use the `e.ColumnIndex` but first you have to check that your are on the right index of cell.